# Flatten sub array by another value in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, flatten

I'm new to Python's data structures and I want to flatten a sub array according to another value in an array :

```
have = [(16, ['1', '2', '3', '4']), (17, ['1', '2'])]
want = [(16,1),(16,2),(16,3),(16,4),(17,1),(17,2)]
```

Comment: `[(x, int(z)) for x, y in have for z in y]`

Comment: Thanks I was wondering how to combine two iterations at once